How to patch nested dependencies in Yocto (swupdate)
Our team recently encountered an error where the libwebsockets commit referenced by meta-oe changed branching schemes from master to main which resulted in the following error:
ERROR: libwebsockets-3.0.0-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Unable to find revision eaa935a80adb38b5cc4d09ce06ec987b87dcddfa in branch master even from upstream
ERROR: libwebsockets-3.0.0-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets.git;protocol=https;'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
ERROR: libwebsockets-3.0.0-r0 do_fetch: Function failed: base_do_fetch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /build/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/libwebsockets/3.0.0-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.99444
ERROR: Task (/opt/Xilinx/petalinux/components/yocto/source/arm/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-connectivity/libwebsockets/libwebsockets_3.0.0.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
This is the bitbake libwebsockets recipe from the meta-oe branch we are using (Thud): https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/blob/thud/meta-oe/recipes-connectivity/libwebsockets/libwebsockets_3.0.0.bb
We're having trouble strategizing the best way to attack this problem - would we need to branch meta-oe and push a commit that then is referenced by the swupdate project?
The meta-oe dependency is nested in our yocto project under the swupdate recipe:
Our Project -> swupdate -> meta-oe -> libwebsockets
Since the dependency link is broken between the meta-oe and libwebsockets, what is the best approach this issue?
